# Concatenate two strings with common elements

Tags: r, string, concatenation

I am working on a simple problem **in R** (but I have not yet figured it out though;p):

Given a vector `vect1 <- c("Andy+Pete", "Mary + Pete", "Pete+ Amada", ..., "Amada + Steven", "Steven + Henry")`. I want to create a new vector `vect2` that contains all the elements in `vect1` **and** new elements that share the following property: for every two strings `"A+B"` and `"B+C"`, we concatenate it into `"A+C"` and add this new element into `vect2`. Can anyone please help me do this?

Also, I want to get **all** the elements standing in front of `+` in each string, is the following code correct?

`for (i in length(vect1)){
    vect3[i] <- regexpr(".*+", vect1[i])
}`

3rd question: if I have a dataframe `d` with a `Date` column in the format `%d-%b` (for example, `01-Apr`), how do I order this dataframe in an increasing order based on `Date`?? Let's just say `d <- c(`01-Apr`,`01-Mar`,`02-Jan`,`31-June`,`30-May`)`.

Comment: Are the elements of `vect1` *always* two people, or can it be 1 or 3+? This sounds like combinatorial "fun".

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to need to split `vect1` into separate columns for the pairs.

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Comment: @r2evans: it is ALWAYS two people, fortunately. How is my `for` loop code?
 
@ManishSaraswat Saraswat: Yes, an example would be `"Mary + Pete"` & `"Pete + Amada"`  (column 2 and 3) = `"Mary + Amada"`. So the new vector would have the size of `vect1` + all the new concatenated elements like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could (should) avoid both `for` loops and the use of external lib if not required.

So this might be a solution:

```
// create data
vect1 <- c("Andy+Pete", "Mary + Pete", "Pete+ Amada", "Amada + Steven", "Steven + Henry")

// create a matrix of pairs with removed white spaces
pairsMatrix <- do.call(rbind, sapply(vect1, function(v) strsplit(gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "", x = v), "\\+")))

// remove dimnames (not necessary though)
dimnames(pairsMatrix) <- NULL

// for all line of the pairsMatrix, find if second element is somewhere else first element. Bind that with the previous pairs
allPairs <- do.call(rbind, c(list(pairsMatrix), apply(pairsMatrix, 1, function(names) c(names[1], pairsMatrix[names[2]==pairsMatrix[,1], 2]))))

// filter for oneself-relationships
allPairs[allPairs[,1]!=allPairs[,2],]

      [,1]     [,2]    
 [1,] "Andy"   "Pete"  
 [2,] "Mary"   "Pete"  
 [3,] "Pete"   "Amada" 
 [4,] "Amada"  "Steven"
 [5,] "Steven" "Henry" 
 [6,] "Andy"   "Amada" 
 [7,] "Mary"   "Amada" 
 [8,] "Pete"   "Steven"
 [9,] "Amada"  "Henry"
```

Concerning your last point, I think a simple sort with proper `Date` object will do it.

Comment: Probably a better solution.  I was too lazy to avoid the loops :).  You got my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it but I did things I probably shouldn't do... like growing objects and nesting `for` loops.  If you want to access all elements in front of the '+', just use `name.matrix[,1]`.

```
vect1 <- c("Andy+Pete", "Mary + Pete", "Pete+ Amada","Amada + Steven", "Steven + Henry")

library(stringr)

name.matrix <- matrix(do.call('rbind',str_split(vect1, pattern = "\\s?[+]\\s?")), ncol = 2)

new.stuff <- c()

for(x in unique(name.matrix[,2])){
  sub.mat.1 <- matrix(name.matrix[name.matrix[,2] == x,], ncol = 2)
  sub.mat.2 <- matrix(name.matrix[name.matrix[,1] == x,], ncol = 2)
  if(length(sub.mat.1) && length(sub.mat.2)){
    for(y in seq_along(sub.mat.1[,2])){
      new.add <- paste0(sub.mat.1[y,1],'+', sub.mat.2[,2])
      new.stuff <- c(new.stuff, new.add)
    }
  }
}

vect2 <- c(vect1, new.stuff)
vect2
#[1] "Andy+Pete"      "Mary + Pete"    "Pete+ Amada"    "Amada + Steven" "Steven + Henry" "Andy+Amada"    
#[7] "Mary+Amada"     "Pete+Steven"    "Amada+Henry"
```

Update:

Third question.  Well there's only 30 days in June.  So you're going to get an NA there.  If it's a data.frame that you're trying to sort based on date, you'll need to use the format `df[order(df$Date),]`.  The `lubridate` package also might be helpful when working with dates.

```
d <- c('01-Apr','01-Mar','02-Jan','31-June','30-May')

d.new <- as.Date(d, format = '%d-%b')
d.new <- d.new[order(d.new)]
d.new
#[1] "2018-01-02" "2018-03-01" "2018-04-01" "2018-05-30" NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. What a solution!! Could you also please help with the 3rd question too?

Comment: No problem.  Ok, I wrote a response.

Comment: I tried that, but R just got frozen (my dataset has 85.56M+ rows). I wonder if this is because the entries are in double-quotation marks??

Comment: Your dataset has over 85 million rows?  No I suspect it got frozen because of the sheer size of sorting that many rows.  Double quotation marks shouldn't matter.  Try breaking off a piece of the huge dataset and sorting that just to see if it's working.

Comment: Yes, over 85M rows, unfortunately. I thought R is specialized to do these types of HUGE dataset. But all it takes for R to get frozen is a simple double `for()` loops. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't the 2nd line in the 3rd question is `d.new <- d.new[order(d.new),]`? While typing this, I am trying to sort a *smaller* data-frame of *only* 69M rows, and R is buffering for more than 40 minutes already;p What an *advanced* statistical package!

Comment: Sorry I've been traveling.  It should be as you wrote it, if it was a data.frame.  But the example I gave is just a vector and therefore, you don't need the comma.